# Concat a list, set as resource attribute

Tags: terraform, terraform0.11

I'm trying to combine two lists and set that as the attribute for a resource and I'm getting an error. Here is the minimal repro:

```
  network_configuration {
    security_groups = "${concat([module.service_base.allow_lb_access_sg], [module.service_base.intraservice_communication_sg])}"
  }
```

I am getting a super unhelpful error

> Error: Error loading modules: module load_balanced_service: Error loading .terraform/modules/188cf031fdce92d75131be4747cedad9/XXX.tf: Error reading config for aws_ecs_service[ecs_service]: parse error at 1:10: expected expression but found "["

It claims line 1 but if you remove that security_groups line everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the docs were super unclear. The way I got around this is

```
security_groups = ["${concat(list(module.service_base.allow_lb_access_sg), list(module.service_base.intraservice_communication_sg))}"]
```

Note that the `list` function is mandatory. If you use `[]` it will still break.

*However*, if one of your inputs is a list, you don't want to put that in `list` because then it would be a list containing your list, e.g. you want

```
security_groups = ["${concat(list(module.service_base.allow_lb_access_sg), var.my_list_type_variable)}"]
```

Further reading: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6657